# Sharepoint 2013 Subsite master page not reflecting

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages

I have a top-level publishing site. Under it is a teamsite. I specified a master page for my teamsite via the page `<teamsite>/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx`

When I reload the teamsite it does reflect the master page I'm expecting to see BUT only for a few seconds. There is some kind of redirection going on because after 3 seconds the teamsite goes back into the default Seattle master page look.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the root site you are not setting the Seattle master page to all the sub sites.